# Open a windows explorer process, and then terminate it again

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, taskmanager

I want to open a windows explorer window and then close it again in C#/VB.Net
 At the moment I can open an explorer window using this code:

```
Dim process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", baseFilePath)
```

However, when I tried to Kill() the process I get an error, and I try and  Close() the window, nothing happens. Apparently, it has something to do with Explorer being a protected resource or something...

When I try to kill() I get: Cannot process request because the process has exited.

```
at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()
```

Does anyone know how to open and then close code in windows explorer specifically?
Cheers!

> Why am I doing this?
>
> We've got network drives which we keep a lot of files on, but for some
>   reason, windows give errors when trying to access the drives
>   programmatically, even when connected to the drives. However, if the
>   user opens windows explorer, windows fixes itself and the program can
>   access the drive. So I want to put this code in an error handler so
>   that the program can re-attempt to open itself.

Comment: Explorer tries to keep only one instance of itself if possible. If one exists, the process you create passes its arguments to the main explorer process and lets it handle the command. After doing this your process terminates itself. This is why you cannot close it.

Comment: OK that seems like a good explanation... However, I can still see these as separate processes in the task manager. Are you saying that there's no way for me to close this new window that I open?

Comment: @Jack I'm assuming you see them under "Processes" in Task Manager, but if you right-click and select "Go to details". You should see the same PID in all cases. You might be able to find the specific window and close that, however.

Comment: Why don't you fix the real issue instead? Since we cannot see, how you try to open files, nor how it fails, nor how the drives are connected, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: You should probably try to fix the source of the problem. What error do you receive? What kind of network shares are these? Mapped to a logical unit (like `net use z: ...`). UNC paths? Are the remote shares *sleeping*? The remote drives are managed by Windows power saving and need to be restarted? Usb devices (same sleeping status)? NAS/CAS? Have you tried to *wait* until they are ready?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i did it :

killed the explorer process by [name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_GetProcesses)

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }

                Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "explorer.exe"));
```

Also i added app.manifest file and below snippet in it to grant the application admin privileges

```
< requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```